# How to open .tvs file in any other software apart from TeamViewer or using the TeamViewer Host version?

Tags: media-player, media-converter, video-player

I have the normal version of the TeamViewer installed on my Macbook and my colleague has the Full version of TeamViewer. During our conversation, he recorded the call and he sent me the file with the `.tvs` extension. I tried opening it directly but it does not open in any player such as my TeamViewer, VLC, etc.

After searching a lot I got to know that it has to be converted and only the Full version of the TeamViewer is capable of doing it. I also found the website which converts the file `https://tvstomp4.com/` but it's paid and the recording is pretty huge (around 2 hours) so its not a good option for me.

I wanted to know are there any Media Players that are available which can play the `.tvs` file? or are there any software available for Macbook which allows me to convert the file to `.MP4`

Comment: it seems like the instructions [here](https://www.videoconverterfactory.com/tips/convert-tvs-to-mp4.html) suggest that there is an option within teamviewer to convert the files to another format. while these instructions seem to be for windows, it may be possible to use it for mac as well. if not this format may be supported by ffmpeg, which is a popular command-line video conversion tool

Answer (score 0):

TVS files are, as of 2018, not supported by video player software. The only way to view these videos is by using TeamViewer directly. More specifically, you need the full version of TeamViewer, the host version won't suffice. All users of TeamViewer can record their sessions if they choose to do so. For further information kindly visit: https://filext.com/file-extension/TVS